# LDAP: what objectClass to use for a service account?

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I'm using Apache Directory Server to create a company directory. As well as people in my organisation, I have a few service accounts. These are used by applications (not people) to connect to LDAP.

What objectClass should I use for these service accounts? I am currently using inetOrgPerson, which works, but doesn't seem ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I used an *account* and a *simpleSecurityObject*. These are the minimum object classes that have everything a service account needs.

Comment: Same conclusion I had. 

Comment: example would be nice...